# Algorithm to condense 2D array for a tetris-like game

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I started from the bottom of the board and search the rows upwards. if it finds an occupied slot, it  is suppose to keep setting the object down 1 slot until it hits the bottom of the board. However it doesn't do that,

I want my loop to set the free location with the object and then clear the spot that the object was just in. this method is called after new colorshapes are added to the array (which sometimes deletes pieces in _tiles and leaves them floating in mid air)

```
//ColorShape is an abstract class that can either be a java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double or java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double
private static ColorShape[][] _tiles = new ColorShape[8][16]; 


public void condenceTiles(){
    ColorShape _colorShape;   
    for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--){
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            if(_tiles[j][i] == null && _tiles[j][i-1] != null) {
                //System.out.println("im condencing");
                _colorShape = _tiles[j][i-1];

                _tiles[j][i] = _colorShape;
                _tiles[j][i-1] = null;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

---

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D aBetterPen = (Graphics2D)g;    
    _proxyPiece.fill(aBetterPen);

    for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8;j++){
            if(_tiles[j][i] != null)
                _tiles[j][i].fill(aBetterPen);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
public abstract class ColorShape
{
    private RectangularShape _shape; //component
    private Color _borderColor, _fillColor;
    private double _rotation;
    private final int STROKE_WIDTH = 2;
    private boolean _isCounted;
    private int _type; //1 is rectangle, 2 is circle

    // removed a lot of methods/constructor so I can show draw and fill methods 

    public void draw (java.awt.Graphics2D aBrush){
        Color savedColor = aBrush.getColor();
        aBrush.setColor(_borderColor);
        Stroke savedStroke = aBrush.getStroke();
        aBrush.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH));
        aBrush.rotate(_rotation, _shape.getCenterX(), _shape.getCenterY());
        aBrush.draw(_shape);
        aBrush.rotate(-_rotation, _shape.getCenterX(), _shape.getCenterY());
        aBrush.setStroke(savedStroke);
        aBrush.setColor(savedColor);
    }
    public void fill (Graphics2D aBrush){
        Color savedColor = aBrush.getColor();
        aBrush.setColor(_fillColor);
        aBrush.rotate(_rotation, _shape.getCenterX(), _shape.getCenterY());
        aBrush.fill(_shape);
        aBrush.rotate(-_rotation,_shape.getCenterX(),_shape.getCenterY());
        aBrush.setColor(savedColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider clarifying your question. Begin by assuming that we have no idea what the rest of your program looks like or how this code fits in with that program.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry I updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

1. You need to iterate one row fewer than you have in total since each operation covers two rows. If you access 15+1 that will cause an OOB exception because the array has only 16 rows and counting starts with 0.
2. You don't need a while loop in addition to the two for loops. The next iteration of the outer loop will take care of blocks above.

Fix (assuming 15 is the bottom and 0 the top):

```
public void condenceTiles(){
  for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--){
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
      if(_tiles[j][i] == null && _tiles[j][i-1] != null) {
        _tiles[j][i] = _tiles[j][i-1];
        _tiles[j][i-1] = null;
      }
    }
  }
  repaint();
}
```

p.s. `col` and `row` may be better names for the loop counters.

Comment: this is a nice solution, but for some reason they dont show up i put repaint() at the button of the if statement but nothing happens. It is working because I did a System.out.println() test message inside the if statement. I think it is because of the = operator. When I go to fill the ColorShape with repaint() it loses its ability to paint

Comment: repaint() should be correct at the end though. Maybe there is an issue with the paint() method? Can you add the code that paints the array to the question?

Comment: I added my paintComponent method and I tried messing around with a local variable too with no luck yet. The array shapes stay "burned" onto the panel while they are removed from the array

Comment: The problem seems to be that the array indices are not taken into account for the drawing position. fill() should take i/j as parameters and use them.